# Loss of users developing for ios5

Tags: xcode4, ios5

in my apps use storyboards ios5 content. If realized my apps for ios5, I would like to know how many potential users who do not have ios5 I lose? thanks

Comment: My guess is you'd lose about 2/3rds of potential "customers".  But only a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of November 9 you would lose about 60% of the customer base, but that's only a few weeks after release.  As time goes on that percentage will shrink a lot.

http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-57321295-37/ios-5-on-almost-40-percent-of-iphones/

If the feature makes development that much easier, then go ahead and use ios5.  If it's a minor convenience, then stick with ios4 (but make sure it also works well on ios5!).